# Angular: Error while create new project (Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

*Angular CLI*: 10.0.4 
*Node*: 12.18.3 
*npm* : 6.14.6

Every time when I try to create new angular project errors appear.
It will hang on (Installing packages...) then error comes out
Below some lines from log file.
Also, I tried:

```
sudo npm cache clean --force
```

and it didn't help.

Please, help on this

```
2621 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/compiler@~10.0.5 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...{"integrity":"sha512-'
2622 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@~10.0.5 Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...":{"integrity":"sha51'
2623 silly pacote range manifest for zone.js@~0.10.3 fetched in 9ms
2624 silly resolveWithNewModule zone.js@0.10.3 checking installable status
2625 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
2626 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 48427ms
2627 silly saveTree newproject@0.0.0
2627 silly saveTree ├─┬ @angular/animations@10.0.7
2627 silly saveTree │ └── tslib@2.0.0
2627 silly saveTree ├── @angular/common@10.0.7
2627 silly saveTree ├── @angular/core@10.0.7
2627 silly saveTree ├── @angular/forms@10.0.7
2627 silly saveTree ├── @angular/platform-browser@10.0.7
2627 silly saveTree ├── @angular/router@10.0.7
2627 silly saveTree ├── rxjs@6.5.5
2627 silly saveTree ├── tslib@2.0.0
2627 silly saveTree └── zone.js@0.10.3
2628 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...{"integrity":"sha512-'
2628 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
2628 verbose stack     at parseJson (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/json-parse-better-errors/index.js:7:17)
2628 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/body.js:96:50
2628 verbose stack     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
2628 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
2629 verbose cwd /home/eve/Desktop/Practice_programming/angular/newproject
2630 verbose Linux 4.18.0-25-generic
2631 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--quiet"
2632 verbose node v12.18.3
2633 verbose npm  v6.14.6
2634 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...{"integrity":"sha512-'
2635 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your node js version,
try to clean your npm cache: `npm cache clean --force`,
also, try to update your angular CLI version `npm install npm@latest -g`

Comment: I tried as you recommended, now error changed to npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."dependencies":{"fsev'

Comment: did u tried this command npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular ?

Comment: After command npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular it is installed some packages. Then I tried to create new project and got this error :npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...0.7.3":{"name":"ts-no'

Comment: so please try npm cache clean --force in administration mode , if you are using windows please delete this file C:\Users{{your-username}}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache then npm cache verify then npm i npm@latest -g then npm install angular/cli@latest -g it should works and restart your computer every step should be in Admin mode . good luck

Comment: It works. I tried many things like changing different version of node and npm and angular and npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular.Not sure which one was useful but project was created after restarting my laptop